# data binding image link using deserialized json data in c# windows phone

Tags: c#, json, windows-phone-7, serialization, binding

i had some json data so i deserialized it and bind the data to the listbox to show the data in text blocks....now the problem is i am trying to add an image in the same list box and want to bind the image source using the data of deserialized object

i mean
the link for the image contains some text which is present in the deserialized data which will change with the change in data....

**can anyone tell me how can i use the data of the deserialized object and then make a new string to pass the image source to bind it to the image present in listbox??**

thanks in advance...

update:

**here is the listbox part of xaml**

```
<ListBox x:Name="listdata" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" ItemsSource="{Binding data}" Height="0" Margin="0,72,0,0">
        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0" DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <Image Grid.Row="1" Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Name="image1" Stretch="None" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="50" Source="{Binding PicLink}" />
                        <TextBlock Height="50" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,6,0,0" Name="textBlock1" Text="{Binding name}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" TextAlignment="Center" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                        <TextBlock Height="Auto" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="6,42,0,0" Name="textBlock3" Text="{Binding timedata}" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="Auto" MinHeight="0" TextWrapping="Wrap" />
                    </Grid>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

**here is the part of c# code:**

```
public class Datum
    {
        public string timedata { get; set; }
        string part = string.Empty;
        public string parts { get { return part; } set { part = value; } }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public string PicLink { get { return string.Format("google.com/{0}/image",part); } }
    }
```

everything is working fine except the image.....image part also works when i replace the PicLink to return a static url instead of variable one

Comment: to be more specific i just want to bind data to image element present in xaml using the data from c# object...

Comment: Do you send this images (bit64 encoded or how ever) with you json data or are they stored at the app (on the phone)?

Comment: @DominikKirschenhofer

string parts=string.Empty;
public string part{get {return parts;} set {parts=value;}}
public string imagelink{get{return string.Format("http://google.com/{0}/image",parts);

this is the code...all this code is present in the same class and part is the method which i deserialized and then using it's value to  create the link for the image and then binding the imagelink to the image element in xaml

any help???

Comment: so your json string contains an url part of an image and you want to use this url to display it by binding it to an Image? This does not work as I know.

Comment: @DominikKirschenhofer yes you are right...can you tell me why is it not possible.......when i am using a static part instead of the string parts for example if i return string.Format("google.com/user/image"); then it is working absolutely fine but when i edit the string with a variable like parts then it does not work

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display images from the web you have to download them first.
This can be a problem for lists because it is timeconsuming.

Have a look at this question to see how it can be done: [How to display an image from web in wp7?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8909974/how-to-display-an-image-from-web-in-wp7)

If it is possilble to include the images into your package or cache them in isolated storage somehow it would be better!

**UPDATE:**

You have to add a property of type "BitmapImage" to your class. (Maybe byte[] also works, don't know now, plz try it) Than you can bind the ImageSource of the Image in the DataTemplate to this property. If you are using this class for the json serializer it should not matter because the serializer will just ignore it at deserialization. To be more secure just do not flag ist with the "DataMember" attribute. It could look like:

```
private string _urlString;
[DataMember]
public string UrlPart
{
    get { return _urlString;}
    set 
    {
        _urlPart = value;
        LoadImage(); // in this function you do the downloading stuff
    }
}

private BitmapImage _itemImage;
public BitmapImage ItemImage
{
    get {return _itemImage;}
    // you can also add a setter if needed
}
```

Comment: the images will keep changing every time i run the application so i cannot store them or cache them.....i have to download them everytime i run the app

Comment: I was afraid of that... so be aware of the traffic, time and memory usage! Hope the linked question shows you how to do it.

Comment: the link you replied shows me the method in which i have to download the image and then use it but in my case i have to pass the changing url of the image to the image element of the xaml.....i cannot create a separate method for it as the image element is present inside a listbox which is binded with the deserialized object so i have to put the image url in the same class.........(as i am new to c# and windows phone so may be my question may sound stupid....any reply will be helpful in making me learn something thanks)

Comment: i was doing a very silly mistake in my method....i by mistake was calling a different method....i was such a fool not to see that....my method was right...anyway thanks for your reply and using your time.....Problem Solved!! :)